# Fullscreen paging without jquery

Tags: javascript, scroll, fullpage.js

I'd like to such behavior to my project, but I use ember fastboot, so I cant use jQuery

is there some non-jquery plugins like fullPage.js?

Here is example what I need:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Comment: You should add some code and be more specific. Opinion-based questions are removed on SO.

Comment: I get it, but have no idea what code to past, maybe just example is enough?

Comment: If you go and [download the fullPage package](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/), than you will see the **pure javascript** library you can use. It is inside the `pure javascript (Alpha)` folder. May you have any troubles using it, than you can post a real question here.

Comment: Really! Thx u a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/pure%20javascript%20%28Alpha%29 It's an alpha project, don't use in production environments

Comment: Marcos, its much more better than nothing and I think its better than I can create on my own, maybe some another library?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, you can always use the pure Javascript version of fullpage.js itself:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/pure%20javascript%20%28Alpha%29

[Demo online](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/pure-javascript/)

It hasn't been as highly tested as the jQuery one, but it seems there are not many complains about it.